# Projects not starting after DDEV update?

Tags: ddev

I was trying to get Xdebug working with DDEV and VSCODE. Finally, I decided to try to update DDEV to the latest version. I did that, and somehow Xdebug started working, which was great. Then I shut everything down and took a break.

When I started everything up again, I found that the existing projects wouldn't start anymore. That is, ddev start just hung. But I found that when I created a new project, it acted normally. I tried various deleting strategies (ddev delete), but that wasn't enough. I did find that deleting the entire .ddev directory and reconfiguring made it possible to create a new project for a folder, but that seemed a bit drastic.

So, I'm guessing that somehow, that updating got something out of sync in existing projects.

Any pointers to what I might do to investigate or fix those existing projects so that they can start?

Comment: Mots likely something is wrong with your docker provider, but you don't give any information about what OS you're on or Docker provider or anything else. Please take a look at the Troubleshooting instructions, https://ddev.readthedocs.io/en/latest/users/usage/troubleshooting/ - and do the normal things like rebooting your computer, restarting docker, etc.  If you want help, show what's actually happening with the projects you're trying to start. Probably coming over to Discord is a better way to get this kind of support, https://discord.gg/hCZFfAMc5k